# ExtJS - Change the tooltip on an action column depending on the value

Tags: javascript, extjs, dynamic, tooltip

I am trying to change the tooltip on a icon in an action column dynamically.

```
    id : 'valueActionColumn',
    sortable : false,
    xtype : 'actioncolumn',
    items : [ {
        icon : 'myimg',
        tooltip : 'Value 1',
        getClass: function(v, meta, rec) {                                      

            if (rec.data.value != "HELLO")
                meta.column.items[0].tooltip = 'VALUE 2';
        }
    } ]
```

What I want is for when the value of `rec.data.value` is "Hello", I want it to change the tooltip to be "Value 2". However, it is setting the tooltip for the first record in the grid to be "Value 1" and then every other action column tooltip to be "Value 2". I would like this to be dynamic depending on the if statement.

Could anyone advise me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The code looks somewhat from the middle of nowhere.. this is a part of object, but which one? Please read about http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: IN your `if` statement you giving `rec.data.value != "HELLO"` but in your question you asking "when the value of rec.data.value is "Hello", I want it to change the tooltip to be "Value 2"". Don't you think this is contradict. I created a fiddle for you please add your code an give. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1if0

Comment: Hi, I managed to fix it by using the renderer function outside the items array

Answer (score 3):

I think getTip will work better than getClass

```
getTip: function(value,m,rec){
      if ( rec.data.anyOtherColumn != "HELLO" )
         return 'VALUE 2';
   }
```